# How to store specific Key-Value Pairs from properties file

Tags: java, config

I want to store the key values pair in java from the config.properties file. Problem is it has some other which in dont want to store in array or hashmap.Below is my config.properties file. One thing the line must start with #usergroup and end of line should be End_TT_Executive as described in the file

```
#Usergroup
TT_Executive
#Tilename
KPI
#No of Submenu=3
#Submenu_1
OPs_KPI=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.sl.dst.ibm.com:8443/CAP-T/res/html/underprogress.html
#Submenu_2
Ontime_OnBudget=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.sl.dst.ibm.com:8443/CAP-T/res/html/underprogress.html
#submenu_3
Ops_KPI_Cloud=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.sl.dst.ibm.com:8443/CAP-T/res/html/underprogress.html

#Tilename
Alerting Dashboard
#No of submenu=0
Alerting_Dashboard=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.sl.dst.ibm.com:8443/CAP-T/res/html/underprogress.html

#Tilename
FTE_Dashboard
#No of submenu=3
#Submenu_1
FTE_Market_Sector_TT_Executive= https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.sl.dst.ibm.com:8443/CAP-T/res/html/underprogress.html

#submenu_2
FTE_Account_TT_Executive= http://tntanalytics1.sl1430087.sl.dst.ibm.com/ibmcognos/bi/?pathRef=.public_folders%2FP=false
#Submenu_3
FTE_Laborpool_TT_Executive= https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.sl.dst.ibm.com:8443/CAP-T/res/html/underprogress.html


#Tilename
PCR
#No of Submenu=0
PCR=https://tntanalytics3.sl1430087.sl.dst.ibm.com:8443/CAP-T/res/html/underprogress.html

End_TT_Executive
```

How can I do this? The key value pair are with URL only rest is some title for understanding.

Comment: I've formatted your question so it looks better, please make sure your question is formatted in future. Also please provide details of what you have already tried, including any code that you have tried and doesn't work. You need to show us that you have attempted to resolve this problem yourself and we're not doing the whole work for you without any effort being made from your side

Comment: I have used nothing till now

Comment: Why don't you separate properties into two files. One file contains all properties should be loaded in Java and one file for others?

Comment: requirment is for one file only

Comment: @jagpreetsingh You will get more attention if you make some sort of effort yourself before asking a question. You will not learn anything if you ask someone else to do it all for you.

Comment: thanks will work on thay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your config.properties is like:

```
p1=abc
p2=def
p3=zxc
p4=eva
```

and you want to load p1 and p2 to map.

You can load all properties into Properties instance with:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;

        try
        {
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
            Properties properties = new Properties(); 

            properties.load(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")); // load all properties in config.properties file
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            inputStream.close();
        }
```

Then you create a map:

```
Map<String, String> propertyMap = new HashMap<>();
```

You also need a String[] to store all properties which you want to load to propertyMap.

```
String[] wantedProperties = new String[]{"p1", "p2"};
```

Then you write a for loop to load the properties you wanted:

```
for (String property : wantedProperties) {
    propertyMap.put(property, properties.getProperty(property));
}
```

Now `propertyMap` is what you want.

If you want to store to List:

```
List<String> propertyList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String property : wantedProperties) {
    propertyList.add(properties.getProperty(property));
}
```

This is the way to save to list. It'll help you more if you find the solution yourself.

Comment: thanks it helped me.and how can i store it into array list? and pass the list ?>

Comment: Do you mean get the contents and save into a List?

Comment: @jagpreetsingh , the second propertyList is what you need.